# Notification-like sound effect playing on the background of the IOS verison of my flutter mobile app

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, audio

My Flutter application sometimes plays a notification-like sound continuously every few seconds from the moment the app is opened, but this issue is not present in the Android version, it only happens in the iOS version. What could be the source of this problem, and how can I resolve it? Also the issue is not even consistent it sometimes happen and sometimes don't.

I've tried searching an answer on the internet including stack overflow and chatgpt but nothing seems to work.